# How to change content of tableView by click button?

Tags: ios, json, swift, uitableview, swift2

I have a tableView into my ViewController. I get data from json on load viewController. But I want then click button and get data from another url json and replace data of tableView for new getted data.

I'm using reload function then parse json but the data isn't replaced.

```
 func do_table_refresh()
 {
 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
     self.tableView.reloadData()
    return
 })
 }
```

How can I do this? Is possible?

Comment: Are you actually setting the new data against the same model that the table is reading from? As that call to tableView.reloadData() should work. Try setting a breakpoint on that reloadData() line and also on your cellForRowAtIndexPath method and check it is being called after reloadData()

Comment: A little more code would defenetly help.

Comment: Did you actually refresh the data that your UITableViewDataSource is using?

Answer (score 0):

```
var queue : dispatch_queue_t!
queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)


dispatch_async(queue) { () -> Void in
  // load json data
 }
  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
     self.tableView.reloadData()
       })
  }
```

try this !!!!!!!